# Wavefunctions of the electron in a hydrogen atom

Tags: electrons, wavefunction, hydrogen

Can someone please explain those different electron distributions and what those (2,0,0), (3,0,0), etc. mean.

[image] 
Image source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hydrogen_Density_Plots.png

Comment: Please don't cut and paste on the internet without crediting the author. It's rude.

Comment: Sorry. Added source link!

Comment: What do you need clarified in the description on the source page?

Comment: The answer below is great and what I was looking for, so we can stop the drama!

Comment: It is important to realise that if on the pictures you have spherical harmonics, and properly depicted radial part, this is probably only approximation. For hydrogen atoms, various additional effects are important and this changes wavefunctions in important ways ( eg . Darwin additional terms) which are negleglible in case of heavier atoms

Comment: I think he just said that each sketch is a 2D cut through a 3D resonant standing wave.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the updates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of the electron in the Hydrogen atom is defined by 3 quantum numebrs - its energy level $n$, its angular momentum $l$ and the projection of the angular momentum on the $z$-axis $m$. The energy levels get the values of positive integers $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, the angular momentum of non-negative integers but is restricted to be smaller than the energy level $l=0,1,\ldots,n-1$ and its projection on the $z$-axis is an integer bound by the angular momentum $m=-l,-l+1,\ldots,l-1,l$.

Each of these numbers affect the wave-function (i.e. the probability distribution) of the electron. However only the first of these ($n$) affects its energy. Changing only $l$ or $m$ does not change the energy. The numbers in parenthesis in the picture you put are these three numbers, ordered as such $(n,l,m)$.